# jquery post with datatype=script and jquery mobile with rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I have an application with both mobile and html format types;

In a form there is a field that has to be filled with value computed by a a remote web service.
With jquery I use the $(post) API to invoke a controller action which invokes the web service

```
    $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
```

The controller computes an instance variable...

```
@myvar = myvalue
....
respond_to do |format|
  format.js 
end
```

then returns a .js.erb template. where I set the value of the field in my form

```
$('#mymodel_myfield').val('<%= @myvar %>');
```

This works like a charm in html, but i cannot get it working in mobile views, where I'm using Jquery Mobile with Mobylette gem.

The jquery function in the js.erb template is not executed because rails expects a .mobile.erb file.

I'm also trying to use a different approach for mobile views, ie calling $.post with json or html data type and use the callback function to inject the .mobile.erb template in my jqm view, but cannot find a way to have it working.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, used a slightly different approach but problem is solved.

> Note: I had to use wireshark to be able to see what the hell was sent
>   by rails to the mobile device, because there is no firebug on mobile
>   browsers.... The solution became clear when, looking at data sent back
>   to the browser, i saw that the response included the application
>   layout, while I was expecting to receive only the json string.

1) the button in jqm form used to invoke the controller action is:

```
<div class="ui-block-c">
  <%= link_to "compute", '#', class: 'compute-myval',:"data-role" => "button", :"data-ajax" => false  %>
</div>
```

2) controller action saves result in an instance variable and respond_to json
(controller name is "visits_controller" and controller action is "compute")

```
@total = "value returned from web service"
...
respond_to do |format|
  format.js     #used for HTML views
  format.json
end
```

3) there is a view named

```
app/views/visits/compute.json.erb
```

whose content is

```
{ "total": "<%= @total %>" }
```

4) the jquery code executed when button is pressed is

```
$('form').on('click', '.compute-myval', function(event) {
  var url;
  url='/visit/compute';
  url += '/' + $('#visit_field1').val();
  url += '/' + $('#visit_field2').val();
  url += '/' + $('#visit_field3').val();
  $.ajax( {
    url: url,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (mydata) {
      $('#visit_resultfield').val(mydata.total);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
  });
  return event.preventDefault();
});
```

5) To manage :mobile format I use the Mobylette gem. 
In order to avoid that the controller action triggered via Ajax 
uses the mobile format and that the application.mobile.erb template is applied
I had to set up a couple of config for Mobylette (inside application_controller.rb)

```
include Mobylette::RespondToMobileRequests
mobylette_config do |config|
  config[:skip_xhr_requests] = false
  config[:fallback_chains] = { mobile: [:mobile, :html, :json] }
end
```

Other thing needed is to have under app/layouts a file named application.json.erb 
that only contains one line

```
<%= yield %>
```

**So it works because there is no compute.mobile.erb view, the fallback is :json and the template does not add anything**

6) the output in the rails log is

```
Started GET "/visit/compute/3/78/66" for 192.168.1.7 at 2012-12-22 00:13:35 +0100
Processing by VisitsController#compute as JSON
  Parameters: {"field1"=>"3", "field2"=>"78", "field3"=>"66"}
  Rendered visits/compute.json.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1335ms (Views: 5.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

7) the field "resultfield" in the Jqm form is filled with **total** value.

Mission accomplished...